# Are there advantages to stacking compatible enchantments on tools, weapons and armour in earlier versions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Before 1.11.1, Mending and Infinity can be put on a bow, after which both were mutually exclusive with each other.

The same goes for the multiple types of Protection for 1.14.3 Pre-release 3.

In terms of effectiveness, practicality and difficulty, is it worth going the extra mile to stack these enchantments before these versions and updating to a later version afterwards?

Do they just not work well together, or is there still an advantage?

Comment: This is a bit opinion based, and I think Arqade isn't the place to ask this.

Comment: I'd say it is, but this question is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Is it **worth** it? Yes, unquestionably.

The "time-value" that mere string, XP, and Iron (amortized over anvil uses) would lose by being compiled into such equipment is *negligible* (probably *zero* — they were just sitting in chests anyway / you're not constrained at over the long run by any of them); contrast this with having an **uncraftable exploit-artifact** that provides unlimited ammo, forever.

Now, whether you'll **regret** indulging in an exploit is a separate question… but remember that, while you can always just burn the bows, you can **never** un-miss the window to craft them.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion using both infinity and mending is over-powered and it is definitely worth it but it might seem like cheating to some people.